# How do I implement Infinite scroll on SharePoint Layout pages?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infinite-scroll, layout-page

I've tried to implement Infinite scroll on Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010's layout pages,
but I failed to implement it. 
My guess is that $(window).scroll or $(window).bind('scroll') wasn't apply to the layout pages,
How do I implementation this?

Comment: I"m having the same issues too, i've tried using jQuery scroll to detect scrolling. Even tried the Infinite-Scroll plugin by Paul Irish, and the promising WayPoints jQuery plugin without any luck. Has anyone else had success with implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

To Implement infinite scroll in sharepoint you need to customize the master page
search for the below line in master page and comment

```
var _fV4UI = true;
```

and for body tag use make scrolling="yes"

and you need to manipulate some css .